# How to run a Nextflow pipeline from an arbitrary process?

Tags: nextflow, nextflow-tower

how can I run a a Nextflow pipeline from an arbitrary process?

-resume option is not useful when there is no error but the content of the output file of a process is erroneous and you want to make a run from a selected process onward. Somehow, I could not find a working answer to this simple looking question on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can add checkpoints throughout your workflow declaration. For example, here is a simple pipeline with 2 processes where an input channel is created either from the collection of the output of `Process1` or from the `publishDir` directory from `Process1`. I used the `collect()` function just to show that processing of the `all_p1` channel.

```
workflow ExamplePipe {
  main:
  if( params.skip_p1 == false ){
    Process1()
    Process1
      .out
      .output1
      .collect()
      .set { all_p1 }
  }

  if (params.skip_p1 ){
    Channel
       .fromPath("path/to/Process1publishDir/*.fasta")
       .collect()
       .set { all_p1 }
  }

  Process2( all_p1 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This might be a workaround but I was looking for a simple answer that solves with an option with the run command like: 
`nextflow run -fromProcess step1` 
instead of -resume.

Comment: There isn’t something like that.

Comment: You can just change the name of the parameter to `params.fromProcess1`, and then the command would be `nextflow run example.nf --fromProcess1`. Alternatively, and more clunky imo, you could create the parameter `params.fromProcess` which is used in the workflow declaration alongside if statements to do exactly what you want.
Something like `nextflow run example.nf --fromProcess step1` and in the workflow declaration `if ( params.fromProcess =~ "step1" )` but the difficulty would be to get the later processes to also run without setting multiple repetitive if statements.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution I found is to change the name of the folder for the process under the `work` directory and use -resume option to run.
Then it only runs the last process as I wanted. In general I have updates in the last process and this solution seem to work practical enough for now. If I need to run multiple process in sequence I would change the folder names of those processes too. The relevant folder names are already printed into the terminal by Nextflow after each run.